# Я пишу секундомер на питоне, но что-то не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Вот Код

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

temp = 0
after_id = ' '

def tick():
global temp, after_id
after_id = root.after(1000, tick)
f_temp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(temp).strftime('%M:%S')
label1.configure(text=str(f_temp))
temp += 1

def start_sw():
btn1.grid_forget()
btn2.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
tick()



def stop_sw():
btn2.grid_forget()
btn3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
btn4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
root.after_cancel(after_id)



def continue_sw():
btn3.grid_forget()
btn4.grid_forget()
btn2.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
tick()

def reset_sw():
global temp
temp = 0
label1.configure(text="00:00")
btn3.grid_forget()
btn4.grid_forget()
btn1.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
tick()


root = Tk()

root.title("StopWatch")

label1 = Label(root, width=5, font=("Ubuntu", 100), text="00:00")
label1.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)

btn1 = Button(root, text="Apasa START", font=("Ubuntu", 30), command=start_sw)
btn2 = Button(root, text="Apasa STOP", font=("Ubuntu", 30), command=stop_sw)
btn3 = Button(root, text="Apasa CONTINUE", font=("Ubuntu", 30), command=continue_sw)
btn4 = Button(root, text="Apasa RESET", font=("Ubuntu", 30), command=reset_sw)

btn1.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
root.mainloop()
```

Ошибка

```
File "C:/Users/AOGG/PycharmProjects/sek/sek.py", line 13
temp += 1
^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: и что не работает?

Comment: Сам код даже не запускаеться  не в pycharm и не с Консоли

Comment: сам секундомер хорошии должен быть но не могу доделать  уперся в ощибку в Pycharm

Comment: C:\Users\AOGG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/AOGG/PycharmProjects/sek/sek.py
  File "C:/Users/AOGG/PycharmProjects/sek/sek.py", line 13
    temp += 1
            ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: я ведь ему показал  temp += 1

Answer (score 4):

В каждой функции сделайте отступ после строчки с def:) 4 пробела. И всё заработает. Собственно, "IndentationError" как раз и говорит о том, что в коде, на указанной строке что-то не так с отступами.

Вот, на примере одной из функций.

```
def tick():
    global temp, after_id
    after_id = root.after(1000, tick)
    f_temp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(temp).strftime('%M:%S')
    label1.configure(text=str(f_temp))
    temp += 1
```

Comment: Ребята от Души спасибо Вам Всем , Постараюсь быть Внимательнее в Будущем

Comment: @NovaPrikol, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)